# Display something else than username in Cognito Built-In Sign-In Page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

In AWS Cognito, `username` is unique and cannot be changed, that's why I'm using it with an internal auto-generated ID. Most of Cognito API requests like [`adminGetUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property) only uses `username` as the user identifier.

And this is [recommended by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html):

> If your application does not require a username, you do not need to ask users to provide one. **Your app can create a unique username for users in the background.** This is useful if, for example, you want users to register and sign in with an email address and password.

Everything is working nicely, but I've got problems with the Cognito Built-in Sign-in page:

[image: Gognito Sign-In]

This page is intended to be viewed by the end user, and it is displaying `username`, which I'm using as an internal ID

The Built-in Sign-in page [can be customized but only CSS and logo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html), I cannot see any option to display `preferred_username` or `email` instead of `username`.

Is there a way? A workaround for my use case? Am I using Cognito the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's finally working with `preferred_username`

[image]

[image]

The only thing is that **the really first time** `username` is used instead of `preferred_username`

[image: Gognito Sign-In]

Probably an AWS bug

Comment: Hey there. I also want to use Cognito's “username” attribute with an internal custom user ID (concealed to the user, who will sign in with email), for the same reasons you mentioned.

But idk how to do this, the documentation is confusing. When you did this, what option did you have to pick in “How do you want your end users to sign-up and sign-in?” Was it "Username" or "Email address or phone number"?

Thanks.